# How to render a partial after backend list filter by octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-partial, octobercms-widgets

With octobercms, I want to do statistics after data filtering.  So I useing the list filters, after filter, The lists data is changed, But the partial not render, So I want to know how to render a partial after backend list filter?

Comment: please share more information to understand this like from where you want to render partial ?

Comment: I have a list of orders. I want to count the number of orders, sales, etc. by filtering the order time, order status, etc. I hope that the data can be changed in real time after filtering.

Comment: yeah that I understood but where do you have added this partial which is not rendering ?

Comment: on the list page

Comment: a demo image here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHmO2.png)

Comment: Can you help me solve this problem?